# PyCuda cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel api

Tags: cuda, pycuda

Is it possible somehow to use / launch the cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel api with pycuda?

Hoping to achieve sync at grid level with such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment, no.

You have see for yourself [here](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/search?q=cuLaunchCooperativeKernel&unscoped_q=cuLaunchCooperativeKernel) that the driver API [version](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1g06d753134145c4584c0c62525c1894cb) of that functionality doesn't appear anywhere in the current PyCUDA tree. I would opine that adding support would require a fairly major overhaul of the APIs and I am not confident that it will happen soon.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @FunkyOne: It would be helpful if, at some point, you could accept this answer so that it falls off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag.

Comment: I don't suppose anyone could advise (now some 20 months later) if this would be any closer?

Comment: @FunkyOne: The links in the answer are dynamic and you can click and see for yourself that nothing has changed in the github repository since that answer was written

Comment: Yes I can see that nothing has yet been implemented (and therefore documented). That's not to say that something may now be in development to hope / await for, that wasn't before.
However I'm guessing not.